# Where's Solution Explorer in VS2010 (for mapped TFS project)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, solution-explorer

I am using VS2010. The problem I have is I've mapped the TFS project to my local machine. Now, I can't see anything in the Solution Explorer pane.

To now - I've gone into Tools > Options > Projects & Solutions > General > and "Always show solution" was already checked.

Beyond that, I'm not sure what to do.

Here's what I see... [VS2010 - Mapped TFS Project - No Solution Explorer](https://www.box.com/s/oun8s0g43x3c5y69sovd)

Comment: You need to open your project's solution (.sln) from source control :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had not mapped the solution to my local folder. I didn't know this is the way it works with TFS. All good now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the solution file, then will appear.